# Munkres' proof that topologist's sine curve is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, connectedness, path-connected

I was reading Munkres' proof that topologist's sine curve is not path connected. What confused me was why he bothered to reduce the path $f:[a,c]\to\bar{S}$ to $f:[b,c] \to \bar{S}$. As is understood by me, it is to assure that $x(t)\gt0$ for $t>b$, so that one can always choose $u$ with $0 < u < x(1/n)$ for arbitrary large $n$. To put it in another way, the crucial point is to use the right discontinuity of the point $b$. Is that so? What if one proceed with the entire path  instead? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Your intuition as to the author's reasoning is good. One could consider the full path by restructuring the argument to consider the continuity at the supremum for which the path is contained on $0 \times [-1, 1]$.

Comment: You would have to write $b+\frac1{n+N}$ for some fixed $N$ wherever you've just written $\frac1n$ in Munkres' version, as well as $b$ in place of some of the $0$s, but it can be done.  It's usually considered proper, however, to clean up your argument before publishing.

Comment: The argument could be adapted. All that's needed is to have an $s\in[b,c]$ such that $x(s)=0$ and a $t>s$, $t\in[b,c]$ such that $x(t)>0$. Then you can define a decreasing sequence $t>t_1>t_2>\ldots>s$ such that $y(t_{n})=(-1)^n$ just as Munkres does, and conclude that $y$ cannot be continuous at $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n$ (which might not equal $s$).

Comment: But I think Munkres' version is cleaner, and makes it easier to visualize what's going on.

Comment: @kodiak Thank you very much.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss But I think one has to make sure $x(t) \gt 0$ for **all** $t > s$,$t \in [b,c]$ in order that the proof could proceed?

Comment: @zyy I don't think so. The contradiction is that $y(t_n)=(-1)^n$ and $t_n$ has a limit, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}y(t_n)$ does not exist even though $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n$ does. That means that $y$ cannot be continuous. As for showing the $t_n$'s exist, all we need (inductively) is that $x(s)=0$ and that $\exists u(\sin(1/u)=(-1)^n\& 0<u<x(t_{n-1}))$, because the intermediate value theorem then says $\exists t_n(x(t_n)=u\&s<t_n<t_{n-1})$. So logically this is simpler than Munkres', but I think it's more confusing.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss But how may one pich enough of such $u$'s with $\sin(1/u)=(-1)^n$ from $(0, x(1/n))$, if there is some $t_0$ such that $x(t) = 0$ for all $t\in[s, t_0)$? I think Munkres intentionally chose $b$ as the supremum to rule such cases out.

Comment: This is getting too long for comments, so I've posted a answer.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss Thank you for your patience. It is too late here, I should try to understand it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a purely logical standpoint, Munkres' reduction is not needed.

Let $g(x)=\sin(1/x)$, $0<x\leq 1$. Let $S(x)=(x,g(x))$, the graph of $g$. The key fact is that for any $x_0>0$, there are infinitely many values of $x$ between $0$ and $x_0$ with $g(x)=1$, and with $g(x)=-1$.

Say $f:[a,c]\to\overline{S}$ is a path connecting $(0,0)$ to some point in $S$. Let $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ with $x(a)=0$ and $x(c)=x_0>0$. Set $t_0=c$, and inductively define a sequence $t_0>t_1>\ldots >a$ with $x(t_n)=x_n$ and $g(x_n)=(-1)^n$ for all $n\geq 1$. The mere existence of such a sequence shows that $t\mapsto g(x(t))$ cannot be a continuous function, since $t_n$ must have a limit greater than or equal to $a$, but $g(x(t_n))$ cannot have a limit. If $t\mapsto g(x(t))$ is not continuous, then $t\mapsto (x(t),g(x(t))=f(t)$ isn't either.

The sequence $\{t_n\}$ can be defined inductively. Suppose $t_{n-1}$ has been defined. We know that there is an $x$-coordinate, say $u$, such that $g(u)=(-1)^n$ and $0<u<x_{n-1}$. Now we just need a time-coordinate to go with it: a $t_n$ such that $a<t_n<t_{n-1}$ and $x(t_n)=u$. But $u$ is between $0=x(a)$ and $x_{n-1}=x(t_{n-1})$, so by the intermediate value theorem, $x(t_n)=u$ for some $t_n$ inbetween $a$ and $t_{n-1}$.

This is basically Munkres' argument. The fact that $f$ might not move for awhile--that $f(t)$ might be stationary between $a$ and some $b>a$--turns out to be irrelevant to the logic. However, I do think that Munkres' argument is more appealing from a visual standpoint.

Comment: I think I understand now. It seems my fault is to presuppose that the sequence ${t_n}$ must converge to $a$ in order to make this proof work. But it turns out that ${t_n}$ could converge to any point, and the proof still work.