# An alternative proof that an ordered square is not path connected

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

I am reading Munkres' *Topology*. Munkres gave two examples of spaces that are not path connected:  the ordered square (A.K.A. the unit square in lexicographic order topology) and topologist's sine curve. It seems these two cases are intuitively similar to each other, but Munkres used different techniques to prove them. So I tried to mimic [Munkres' proof in the sine curve case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715691/munkres-proof-that-topologists-sine-curve-is-not-path-connected?noredirect=1#comment9989116_4715691) to prove the path-disconnectedness for the ordered square.

I tried to proceed as follows.
Suppose there is a path $f: [a,c] \to I_o^2$ joining the two points $0 \times 0$ and $1 \times 1$. The set $A = 0 \times [0,1]$ is closed in $I_o^2$, so is $f^{-1}(A)$ in $[a,b]$. So the latter has a largest element $b$. Replace $f$ with its restriction to $[b,c]$; without a loss of generality we also replace $[b,c]$ with $[0,1]$. Then $f$ maps $0$ to some point in $0\times[0,1]$, and any point from $(0,1]$ to some point in $x\times[0,1]$ with some $x\gt 0$.

Then I tried to deduce a contradiction from the continuity of $f$ at the point $0$. It went easy assuming the case $f(0) = 0\times y$ with $y\lt 1$, since one could always find a neighbourhood of $0\times y$ which is completely contained in $0\times[0,1]$. But I could not solve the case where $f(0) = 0 \times 1$. Can we proceed in this way? Or maybe I went into a completely wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always hard to say conclusively that an approach cannot work, but I suspect that's so in this case.

All proofs that the topologist's sine curve $\bar{S}$ isn't path connected, are related to this fact: $\bar{S}$ isn't locally connected.

(Or at least all the proofs I've seen. Some use this fact more or less explicitly. I'd say Munkres' proof uses the reason that $\bar{S}$ isn't locally connected: A small open disk around $(0,y_0)$ will restrict $x$ to an interval $0\leq x<\epsilon$, but the graph of $\sin(1/x)$ in that interval takes on all $y$-values between $-1$ and $1$. Hence the intersection of the disk with $S$ is not connected.)

(Compare with this space: $\bar{T}=\{(0,0)\}\cup T$, where $T$ is the graph of $x\sin(1/x)$. Since $\lim_{x\to 0}x\sin(1/x)=0$, this space is itself a path, i.e., a continuous image of the unit interval.)

The ordered square, on the other hand, *is* locally connected. (Munkres gives this as an exercise.) His proof of its non-path-connectedness appeals instead to the fact that $I_o^2$ isn't second-countable.

The [Hahn-Mazurkiewicz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn%E2%80%93Mazurkiewicz_theorem) is relevant here. It states:

> A Hausdorff space is a continuous image of the unit interval if and only if it is compact, connected, locally connected, and second-countable.

If a topological space $X$ contains a path $f:I\to X$, then the image $f(I)$ with the subspace topology will enjoy all these properties. For the topologist's sine curve, it's local connectivity that fails (for a suitable path); for $I_o^2$, second-countability.

Comment: I agree. It does now seem to me that the proof has to use the second-countability of $I_o^2$.

Comment: Is there some explicit connections between local connectedness and path connectedness? It seems that Munkres wrote only a little about local connectedness and local path-connectedness, nor did he provided enough intuition. I could hardly seen that the proof was related to local connectedness without you mentioning it.

Comment: @zyy The H-M theorem is one aspect of the connection between local connectivity and path connectivity. The proof in the book by Singer & Thorpe makes the relation more explicit. Munkres’ proof takes a step back, and exploits the feature of $\bar{S}$ that’s responsible for it not being l.c.

Comment: @zyy Suppose $x$ belongs to the vertical segment. Intersect a small disk about $x$ with $\bar{S}$, to give a neighborhood of $x$. The connected component of $x$ belongs entirely to the vertical segment, so a path starting at $x$ cannot escape the segment as long as it stays in the neighborhood. But this is true for every point of the vertical segment. With a little work, this can be turned into a rigorous proof.